# puppeteer/Javascript check for network responses in a loop

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, promise, puppeteer

Using puppeteer I am trying to achieve something where I can capture network responses on selection of a dropdown item. It does not have to be immediate, we can select all options one after another, and can use network response later as well, as long as it works smoothly.

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeoptions);
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.target().createCDPSession();
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(1000000);
}

async function getAppointmentData() {
  await page.goto('go to the page URL')
  let appointmentData = [];
  await page.waitForSelector(
      "[id*=dropdownId]"
    );

  for (let option of options) {
    // Selecting an option from a dropdown trigger a network call that I need to record
    await page.select(
        "select#dropdownId",
        option?.id
      )

   /* Check for a network call that contains that option?.id or .json?details
      Sample URL >>>> https://abc.test.com/en/10.json?details  [Where 10 is options?id]
   */
  // After All Items in dropdown is selected, Want to insert response [Array of Objects] to an object like:
   appointmentData.push({
     id: options?.id;
     data: [Array of Objects]
    }]

  } // For Loop Ends

  processAppointments(appointmentData )

}

processAppointments(data) {
  /// 
}

getAppointmentData();
})();
```

I tried using `page.on()` and other methods but not helpful. can someone please help me out here? been stuck for almost one week.

Comment: do the things you `await` in your code return a Promise? if so, then the code should do what you haven't described it should do

Comment: I am new to this,, did not understand. Let me update the questions with more code

Comment: let me type slower - there are some functions you `await` - do they return a Promise?, i.e. is `await` going to do anything useful?

Comment: I tried using await page.on() and other await functions, but did not work for me.

Comment: yes - you do know what `await` is used for? it's not to wait for *any random asynchronous thing* but specifically to *wait for a **Promise** to resolve* - you understand that?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] and share the page you're working with. Where's the dropdown? Which network responses are you trying to capture? Thanks.

Comment: await page.waitForSelector(
      "[id*=dropdownId]"
    ); is the dropdown selector

Answer (score 0):

Your page.on should look something like:

```
page.on("response", response => {
  let match = response.url().match(/(\d+).json/)
  if(match){
    console.log(`option ${match[1]}`)
  }
})
```

Comment: but if add page.on() inside for loop, then it does not work properly..

Comment: It goes before the for loop

Comment: I tried that, but still does not work efficiently. will it capture all the responses that for loop will generate in future as well ?

Comment: Yes, it will and I added the condition to filter the ones you're after.